# dynamic output values input in div element jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are a lot of input, which are generated by the system.

I need to print the values ​​dynamically when a person changes the value
[view my input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfKde.png) 
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6rKj.png)

the system generates inputs automatic ( plug-in) , I became attached to the name , and stretched out the value in a div block, but it at me does not change dynamically when a person clicks on the rocker

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
 {
  
 var value_input = $("input[name*='product-options[1271][58]']").val(); 
 $("#for_my_script").append("<p>" + value_input + "</p>") 
 
});
</script>
```

I will be grateful for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an element's value by `val()` command in jquery. This mostly works. And you can append an event on keyup so u can get the value when it changes.

[here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qqbe3xu/)